# root of the xml file is giving as NONE why?

Tags: python, xml, file, xml-parsing, elementtree

```
from elementtree import ElementTree as ET
tree= ET.parse(r'N:\myinternwork\files xml of bus systems\testonieeebus.xml','r')
root= tree.getroot()
print(root)
```

now the error is in output as it is giving none

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: `ET= open(…)` overwrote previsous definition of ET; ET is now an open file and files don't have attribute 'parse'.

Comment: The `ElementTree` module that comes with Python is in the `xml.etree` package. See http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html. But you are using `from elementtree import ElementTree as ET`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is enough. You don't need to open the file at beginning. `ET.parse` will do it for you if you provide the correct path.

In your code you import the library as ET and then reassign the same variable by opening the file. So `ET.parse()` referes to your file object not to your `elementtree` library.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree= ET.parse('note.xml')
root= tree.getroot()
print(root.tag) # to print root
```

Comment: but the output root is giving as none even though there is a root why? any help

Comment: Accept the answer if its correct. Glad that it helped you

Comment: note.xml is a file I tried did you replace with correct name? What do you really want to print as str?

Comment: from elementtree import ElementTree as ET             
tree= ET.parse(r'N:\myinternwork\files xml of bus                systems\testonieeebus.xml','r')                        
 root= tree.getroot()
fo= open(r'N:\myinternwork\files xml of bus systems\testonieeebus.xml','r')
str= fo.read(100)
print str
print root
i am able to get str but not the root it is giving none..   sry i dont know how to format the code in comment sry for it i am new to stack overflow @Marlon Abeykoon

Comment: I want the root of it only brother!!

Comment: `print(root.tag)` This will print the root

Comment: sry brother i couldn't get ..........                                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\python\installed files\my work\parsingxml.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(root.tag)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'

Comment: Can you post the full xml here or atleast a link to download it?

Comment: I copy pasted it and named the file as note.xml.. and it worked for me

Comment: Can you copy paste it in a xml file named note.xml and keep it where the code located and then run it?