# whatever be the XML file root is always showing as none why?

Tags: python, xml

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

tree= etree.parse(r'N:\myinternwork\files xml of bus systems\sample.xml','r')

root= tree.getroot()

print(root)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [root of the xml file is giving as NONE why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44215454/1255289)

Comment: can anyone please remove the down-vote of the question, I was unable to ask questions now. At that time of asking question , I was new to stack overflow i didn't know much. Now I read the basic prerequisites for asking a question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not parsing the file `sample.xml`, because of the second parameter you provided ('r'), would work if you  did e.g.:

```
tree= etree.parse(open(r'N:\myinternwork\files xml of bus systems\sample.xml','r'))
```

or

```
tree= etree.parse(r'N:\myinternwork\files xml of bus systems\sample.xml')
```

as per [the `xml` doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse):

> xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(source, parser=None)
>   Parses an XML section into an element tree. source is a filename or file object containing XML data. parser is an optional parser instance. If not given, the standard XMLParser parser is used. Returns an ElementTree instance.

Your code has two lines that are not used at all:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
```

and the bigger problem is that it throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

both on Python 2 and 3

therefore you don't seem to be running the non-minimal example code you presented in your question.

With [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/) example 1 from w3schools.com in file `/tmp/xx.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I can run this interactively:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 22 2017, 11:20:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('/tmp/xx.xml')
>>> print(tree)
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x7ff247570e10>
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> print(root)
<Element 'note' at 0x7ff24756d7c8>
>>>
```

Comment: "You are parsing the tuple" is an odd way of explaining the problem. The `parse()` function does take an optional second argument, but that argument must be an `XMLParser` object, not a string. In addition, you are linking to the lxml documentation but the OP is not using lxml.

Comment: @mzjn My bad, I was looking at the wrong documentation (googled for `etree.parse()`)

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree= etree.parse(r'N:\myinternwork\files xml of bus  systems\sample.xml'))
        root= tree.getroot()
     print(root)
    even now output is none any help?

Comment: @nikhilvaliveti Please don't put code in comment, it's unreadable. Make sure your XML is correct/edit your post to include the XML. I'll update my post with what I used to test.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow @Anthon i didn't find any place to show the xml and thought to put here but there is no option to format it that's why i have done that

Comment: @nikhilvaliveti 1) Click on [edit] below **your** post. 2) Copy/Paste the XML at the bottom, with one empty line between the rest of the text and the XML 3) Select the XML (and only the XML) 4) Press the `{}` in the menu bar above the text edit box. 5) Scroll down to see how it looks 6) Click [Save Edits]. If you want to make the most out of [so], learn how to edit, e.g. by just looking at a nicely formatted post, click on edit below and cancel once you have seen how the markup is done.